# Post with CURL to API

Tags: api, post, curl, lamp

I'm having trouble sending a POST request via cURL:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"test@test.com", "password":"testpassword", "verify":"testpassword", first_name="Mo", last_name="Lester"}' http://stuff.com/signup

The error message I've received said the server isn't getting the password, and probably none of the data at all.

I tried posting quotes around the URL, without luck.

New to cURL, forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot quotes around the `first_name` and `last_name` elements and you've included `=` in those assignments instead of the JSON `:` character which results in invalid JSON that the other end won't be able to parse. This is a corrected valid JSON request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"test@test.com", "password":"testpassword", "verify":"testpassword", "first_name": "Mo", "last_name": "Lester"}' http://stuff.com/signup
```

Comment: Too much coffee, not enough sleep.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: I tried the code today.  It still is acting like the variables aren't making it to the api...  

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"test@test.com", "password":"testpassword", "verify":"testpassword", "first_name": "Mo", "last_name": "Lester"}' http://stuff.com/signup

returns a Nonetype error on my first route. I can update the question with code if you need it.

Comment: where's the documentation for that API?

Comment: I'll just start a new thread, because it's probably an issue with my code in Flask.  I tried curl on another api and it worked fine.